# can I use another another image burner besides etcher?

Tags: release-freya

I'm currently on Mac OS 10.7.5, and I'm unable to use the latest Etcher release. Can I use another image burner or do you know if I can obtain an earlier release? I have not been able to find one online. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative too. I can't download etcher. I get dialup speeds and the download always fails before it finishes. Maybe instructions on how to do it with Disk Utility would be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X there is disk utility to burn cd/dvd/usb sticks or [terminal command dd](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/13/burn-an-iso-image-from-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

I know that old releases can be found in their repository, although they don't seem to host compiled binaries or install images. https://github.com/resin-io/etcher